# iOS-Charts: How to include a gap between data points & lines

Tags: swift, swift3, cgcontext, ios-charts, uigraphicscontext

I'm using iOS-Charts with Swift to draw line charts, and I'm looking for a way to place a gap between the data points (circles) and the lines themselves.

Something like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLLzc.png)

I've tried playing around with some values under the `drawLinear` section of `LineChartRenderer.swift`, but I don't know enough about Core Graphics to do anything useful.

Having a white outline for the circles is unfortunately not an option, since I'm displaying multiple datasets with images containing transparent layers, and the datasets need to be able to overlap (as in the example image)

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks :)

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution?